# how to get input text value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want get input text value when I insert a value in input text

and when i click `ADD IN BOOK LIST` button jquery will append in booklist ul tag

**html code**

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>POST TITLE</p>
    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Insert title" required>

    <p>INSERT BOOK NAME</p>
    //user will input value this text box
    <input type="text" name="bookname" placeholder="book name">

    <input type='button' name="addlist" value="ADD IN BOOK LIST">

    <ul class="booklist">
    </ul>

    <input type="submit" id='button'>//create post button

</form>
```

I decide to using `val()` method and i testing using `alert()`

**js code**

```
(function(){
  //get  ADD IN BOOK LIST button
  //get bookname tagname
  var addlist_button = $('input[name=addlist]');
  var book_name = $('input[name=bookname]').val();

  addlist_button.on('click', function(event){
    if((book_name == "")||(book_name == null)){
      alert('fail');
    }
    else{
    alert(book_name);
    }
  });
})();
```

but jquery can't get text value

the `val()`method is only get `value=""`in  tag inline.. but it is useless value

I want get client's valuable text please somebody help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you check the value of the input on page load but not when the user clicks on the button.

So the solution is to check it when user clicks on the button.

```js
(function(){
  //get  ADD IN BOOK LIST button
  //get bookname tagname

var addlist_button = $('input[name=addlist]');
  addlist_button.on('click', function(event){
    
    var book_name = $('input[name=bookname]').val();
    if((book_name == "")||(book_name == null)){
      alert('fail');
    }
    else{
      alert(book_name);
    }
  });
})();
```

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
    <p>POST TITLE</p>
    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Insert title" required>

    <p>INSERT BOOK NAME</p>
    //user will input value this text box
    <input type="text" name="bookname" placeholder="book name">

    <input type='button' name="addlist" value="ADD IN BOOK LIST">

    <ul class="booklist">
    </ul>

    <input type="submit" id='button'>//create post button

</form>
```

http://jsbin.com/niheqo/edit?html,js

Answer (score 1):

Get input value in click event as following:

```
(function(){
  //get  ADD IN BOOK LIST button
  //get bookname tagname
  var addlist_button = $('input[name=addlist]');


  addlist_button.on('click', function(event){
    var book_name = $('input[name=bookname]').val();

    if((book_name == "")||(book_name == null)){
      alert('fail');
    }
    else{
    alert(book_name);
    }
  });
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have defined `book_name` before the event was triggered and at that time it was equal to "".

```
(function(){
  //get  ADD IN BOOK LIST button
  //get bookname tagname
  var addlist_button = $('input[name=addlist]');


  addlist_button.on('click', function(event){
    var book_name = $('input[name=bookname]').val();

    if((book_name == "")||(book_name == null)){
      alert('fail');
    }
    else{
    alert(book_name);
    }
  });
})();
```

Comment: thank you @nizzik you solved my problem! thank you very much!